# Create a file and display the words starting with letter given by the user in C

Tags: c, file-handling

I have written the following code. I am using VS Code. The program is storing the data into the file but it's not displaying the words on the terminal.
After entering the EOF command (ctrl+z) nothing happens. The code does nothing and doesn't stop either.

I have written the following code. I am using VS Code. The program is storing the data into the file but it's not displaying the words on the terminal.
After entering the EOF command (ctrl+z) nothing happens. The code does nothing and doesn't stop either.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
int main() 
{
    FILE *fp; 
    int c=1, i; 
    char alpha, str[30]; 
    printf("Enter the letter: "); 
    printf("%s", &alpha); getchar();
    
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Hello.txt", "w");
    
    printf("Enter paragraph: ");
    
    char ch;
    
    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF)
    {
        fputc(ch, fp);
    }  
    fclose(fp);
    
    fp = fopen("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\Hello.txt", "r");
    while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        if(ch==alpha)
        {
            i=0;
            str[i]=ch;
            i++;
            while((ch==fgetc(fp))!=' ')
            {
                str[i] = ch;
                i++;
            }
            str[i]='\0';
            puts(str);
        }
        else
        {
            while((ch=fgetc(fp))!=' ')
            {
                continue;
            }
    
        }
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `ch` should be declared `int`, not `char`, because `EOF` is not a valid `char`.